# A doubt on Doppler's Effect

Tags: doppler-effect

I was solving a problem based on **Doppler's Effect**

The Question is :

> A car is moving towards a stationary observer with speed 10m/s . The car blows a horn of frequency 640Hz for 10 seconds . If speed of sound in air is 330m/s , then :
>
> (A) Frequency of horn heard by stationary observer is 660Hz
>
> (B) The time duration during which observer hears the horn is 12s
>
> (C) Frequency of horn heard by driver of car is 640Hz
>
> (D) The time duration during which obeserver hears the horn is 10s

This question has multiple options correct and the correct options are **A , C , D**
Options A and C were easily understandable and were solved by me , but I faced a problem in option D how to approach it and understand it and how to link the time duration for which the horn would be heard by observer .

It's a long question:D but please do help !

I am also attaching the photo of the question that is written as well .

[image: Question]

Comment: Hi Ayush Shankaram. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can work out the length of the sound by counting oscillations. You know the sound lasted for $10\,\text{s}\times 640\,\text{Hz} = 6400$ oscillations. That number is the same for anyone hearing the sound. Therefore, the duration of the sound for the stationary observer is $6400 / (660\,\text{Hz}) \approx 9.7\,\text{s}$.

To figure out whether you should choose (D), you have to figure out which of the following is true:

1. There is a typo in it – it's supposed to say "driver" not "observer" – and it's supposed to be correct.
2. You're supposed to round to the nearest second (even though the problem doesn't say so) and it's supposed to be correct.
3. They made the mistake of thinking that the time would be the same for everyone, so it's supposed to be correct.
4. It's supposed to be wrong.

Apparently one of 1-3 is the case, but I don't know which.

Comment: Thank You very much. got your method

Answer (score 1):

Your difficulty lies in trying to prove a false statement.  $D$ is not correct.

Assume that the approaching vehicle is emitting this sound for $10$ seconds, then silent for $10$ seconds, then sounding for $10$ seconds, then silent, and so on.

So the vehicle is producing, from its point of view, a 640 Hz sound, modulated at $0.1$ Hz.  The Doppler shift for the stationary observer applies to both these frequencies;  the modulating frequency is higher, the length of a modulating pulse is shorter, and the time for each pulse to reach the observer is less.

This point nearly ruined the Cassini-Huygens probe to Saturn. https://www.thespacereview.com/article/306/1

Briefly, the Cassini probe, as it entered the Saturn atmosphere would decelerate rapidly and at a changing rate, causing the signal back to Huygens to have a rapidly changing Doppler shift.  The designers of the receiver allowed for the shift in transmitted frequency, but failed to allow for the Doppler shift in the demodulated signal:

> Here was the crucial flaw. The Doppler shift did not only change the
> frequency of the incoming signal, it also squeezed it into a slightly
> shorter time period. As a result, Cassini’s receiver would have been
> unable to recognize the timing pulse in its expected location, and
> thus the incoming data stream would become unreadable.

> We have a technical term for what went wrong here,” British scientist
> John Zarnecki of the Planetary Science and Space Research Institute of
> Britain’s Open University told reporters. “It’s called a cock-up.

Fortunately, the problem was detected early in the cruise phase of the mission, and the Saturn encounter was redesigned to meet the reduced capability of the communication channel.

Comment: thank you very much...very interesting info